# Differences in asking what the time is

Tags: phrase-meaning

> What is the time?
> What time is it?

What are the differences between the above two sentences?

Comment: There is no difference and both are equally common.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelHarvey that there is no difference in meaning. But for this native speaker of American English, *What time is it?* is much more commonly used than is *What is the time?*

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum - I often hear 'What's the time?', maybe it is, as you say, a regionalism (I am UK based). As kids we used to play a game called 'What's the time, Mister Wolf?'.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum: I don't see any significant difference between [AmE usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What+time+is+it%2CWhat+is+the+time&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) and [BrE usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What+time+is+it%2CWhat+is+the+time&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) in this respect. It's more a matter of *personal preference*, I'd say.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, so it seems that my intuition about the two variants’ relative frequency  reflects usage on both sides of the pond.

Comment: ngram, and google search, each say one choice is 10 times more common than the other. so they're likely not equally common.

Answer (score 0):

They are simply two different ways of asking the same question.

It isn't unusual:

- What is the colour? / What colour is it?
- What number is it? / What is the number?

When you use the pronoun 'it', as in the latter question, it should always be clear what "it" is. In the case of "*what time is it?*" it would be assumed you meant the *current time*. The same is true of '*the*' time. When you use the definite article it should be clear which specific thing you mean. Without any other context, it would be assumed that you meant *the current time*.

There may be contexts where you are speaking about a future event, and "the time", or the time of "it" may refer to that previously mentioned event and not the current time.